# Caliburn - IBusyService Logic

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, caliburn

Say I have a View with a BusyIndicator and a Button that is attached to an Action.

What is the best way to make the Button disabled when Show.Busy() is yielded from the action?  Is there an easy way to hook up a CanMyAction boolean property?

Right now, I have inherited DefaultBusyService to get the job done, but it seems ugly to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my discussion on codplex [here](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/discussions/249590).

On VMs that require it, I will implement a ICanBeBusy interface that my custom IBusyService will interact with.  Then I can easily use this property to disable the button.